# Install graphite with apache .4 on ubuntu 14 error

Tags: apache, graphite

```
mod_wsgi Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/usr/share/graphite-web/graphite.wsgi'
```

I copied only apache-graphite.conf to /etc/apache/sites-available, why does it complain about graphite.wsgi?

Content of apache-graphite.conf:

```
import os, sys
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'graphite.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi

application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()


from graphite.logger import log
log.info("graphite.wsgi - pid %d - reloading search index" % os.getpid())
import graphite.metrics.search
```

Comment: have you mixed apache-graphite.conf and graphite.wsgi ?

Answer (score 0):

graphite.wsgi is the [wsgi application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Server_Gateway_Interface) callled by your apache webserver to answer incoming requests.

The apache-graphite.conf site defines a wsgi application running django which will process requests using graphite code. I guess it looks more like this : https://github.com/graphite-project/graphite-web/blob/0.9.x/examples/example-graphite-vhost.conf

graphite.wsgi usually looks like : https://github.com/graphite-project/graphite-web/blob/0.9.x/conf/graphite.wsgi.example